# Carousel View is not showing in Windows Phone 8.1 in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
I have added "**CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.dll**" file to WindowsPhone platform in VisualStudio.
```

And In PCL, I have added the code for CarouselView as follows :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <carusalView:CarouselViewControl Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 InterPageSpacing="10"
                                 Position="0"
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 x:Name="CarosoulItem"
                                 ShowIndicators="False"
                                 IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                                 PageIndicatorTintColor="Yellow"
                                 CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="Green">
                        <carusalView:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </carusalView:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </carusalView:CarouselViewControl>
                </Grid>
```

In Android and IOS, Here also I have downloaded Carousel from Nuget Package Manager.  Carousel is working here.

But, For Windows also I did Same thing. Here its not showing Carousel.

****NOTE:**I am not using UWP.**

So, please  anyone find the solution for this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, [that project](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) does not support any Windows platform other than UWP.

Comment: Yeah, That only the question i asked. For UWP, Carousel will supprt but , For Windows Phone 8.1 it won't support.....